# HttpPostedFileBase has error (MVC) red underline

Tags: c#, image, model-view-controller, controller

I am not able to use the HttpPostedFileBase as I have red underline under HttpPostedFileBase in my Controller Action. How do I solve it?

```
 public IActionResult Add(TheMobileSuit themobilesuits, HttpPostedFileBase photo)
```

Comment: What am I missing??

Comment: You mean I should replace HttpPostedFileBase to IFormFile??

Comment: Welcome to SO - please delete your comments above because of useless text (see: How do I solve it?) and duplicate (see your comment on answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .Net Framework you'll want to make sure your project references `System.Web.Abstractions`. If you're using .Net Core you'll need to use `IFormFile` because `HttpPostedFileBase` does not exist in Core.

IFormFile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-3.0

HttpPostedFileBase: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfilebase?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You mean I should replace HttpPostedFileBase to IFormFile??

Comment: If you're using .Net Core, yes.

Comment: How do I use IFormFile to save and upload image file? What must I code it? The image should be save to a folder (Images) under wwwroot, then the path name to the image (~/Images.example.jpg) to my local database.

Comment: There appears to be some pretty good documentation for uploading files in .Net Core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0#file-upload-scenarios